# How can I avoid an invalid syntax error in these lines of Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
z=2
while z > 1:
    print("error "*1000000)
    z+=1
    if z == 10
        break
```

Whenever I run this program, I am returned an "invalid syntax" error. What would I have to do here to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `:` at the end of `if z == 10` e.g.

```
if z == 10:
```